# Keycloak: Enforce re-authentication on an important / critical user operation

Tags: keycloak

Is there a possibility to enforce re-authentication on important / critical user operation in the application?

In our app, the user can perform some critical operations, where we would like to enforce an re-login / re-authentication, to ensure that the right person ist behind the pc. Even though the user is authenticated via SSO, we need that the user enter his login credentials again. Beside of that we need a different expiration timer for this special operation (shorter then our default token expiration).

I know, keycloak provides a possibility to configure different authentication flows in different clients but i have no idea how to combine different clients in a single session?¿ (and if it is possible at all).

I hope, someone has an idea how we can secure such a kind of this critical operations.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes and no. For SSO/SAML users we wanted to keep the SSO for the main application but re-login for special actions. So we created a second tenant which is also configured against SAML like the main tenant, but here we disable SSO / force re-authentication and in our application we check manually the token of the second authentication. This solution is not that nice, but for now we don´t see other options.

Answer (score 2):

Keycloak seems to call it "Step-Up Authentication". You can configure a client to have different Levels Of Authentication (LoA), for example "silver" or "gold". The normal login would be silver. For critical operations the application can ask for the gold level, and force the user to give his password again. The gold level can be configured to be valid only for a short time or only one operation.

This video helped me to understand it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLCBMQIqwAc

Comment: Thank you to sharing this option. We will perform a research if this solution fits our needs and then i will share the results :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes i'ts possible.

**org.keycloak.authentication.RequiredActionProvider**

```
/**
 * Defines the max time after a user login, after which re-authentication is requested for an AIA. 0 means that re-authentication is always requested.
 *
 */
default int getMaxAuthAge() { return Constants.KC_ACTION_MAX_AGE; }
```

You must create your own RequiredAction! And define getMaxAuthAge with your customer's convenience.